# php file() handle errors when it goes something wrong

Tags: php

I'm using php file() function for getting the xml content into array like:

```
$XMLContent=file("http://www.domain.com/file.xml");
```

but I don't how to handle error like if the file will not exists or website.
I tried to use this way:

```
try {
  $XMLContent=file("http://www.domain.com/file.xml");
  ....
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

but I always get two errors in my error log if the website is wrong:

1) file(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in

2) failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in

`var_dump($XMLContent);` shows false

if the file doesn't exists then I don't get errors in my log but 
`var_dump($XMLContent);` shows other stuff that I don't need

How to handle properly these errors and the errors will not log in the error file?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = fopen ("http://www.example.com/", "r");
if (!$file) {
    echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
    exit;
}
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Comment: this doesn't help because I can do this as well like this: `if (!$XMLContent=file("http://www.domain.com/file.xml")) {`